# Prove $C_c(R^n)$ is not dense in $L^\infty(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

My ideas is this:

the function $f(x)=1\in L^{\infty}(R^n)$ but can't be approximated by functions $g$ with compact support in norm $||.||_{\infty}$ because $|g(x)-1|=1$ for $x$ sufficiently large?

Comment: Correct, given any particular $g \in C_c,\| f - g \|_{L^\infty} \geq 1$, by examining some positive measure set outside the support of $g$.

Comment: I don't understand.Can you write better the proof,please?

Comment: $\{ x : |f(x)-g(x)| \geq 1 \}$ contains the entire complement of the support of $g$, so it has positive measure (infinite measure actually), so $\| f - g \|_{L^\infty} \geq 1$.